# Comma-separated column value match in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table I have a column `Specialities` with values stored like this:

```
4' Tarps, 6' Tarps, 8' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card
```

i.e. values are stored in a comma-separated manner.

I want to fetch the column in `LIKE` operator or any other operator which value is match in that column.

This is what I'm trying:

```
DECLARE @EquipmentServiceType nvarchar(max)

SET @EquipmentServiceType = '|Coil Racks|Hazmat|TWIC Card';
SET @EquipmentServiceType = REPLACE(@EquipmentServiceType,'''','')
SET @EquipmentServiceType = REPLACE(@EquipmentServiceType,'|',''',''')

select Specialities 
from CarrierData 
where Specialities like '%' + ''',''Coil Racks'',''Hazmat'',''TWIC Card''' + '%' 
    or Specialities like ',%' + ''',''Coil Racks'',''Hazmat'',''TWIC Card''' + ',%'
```

How to match the `comma separated` column in SQL Server?

Here is the table image:
[the table column is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vpAV.png)

Comment: add sample data & desired result.

Comment: It is no good idea to save values as csv. Redesign your database

Comment: i have already add in the question

Comment: 4' Tarps, 6' Tarps, 8' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card

Comment: the data are stored like 4' Tarps, 6' Tarps, 8' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card.........Here how can i fetch the row which matching Coil Racks, Edge Protectors both the column or single one column

Comment: @asasasaa u want match only string value ???

Comment: yes exactly i want to match

Comment: select Specialities from CarrierData where Specialities like @EquipmentServiceType

Comment: in @EquipmentServiceType want to match the string value

Comment: @asasasaa ur question is unclear pls. add sample data & desired result .

Comment: what you unclear pls ask me

Comment: There is a column name Specialities in table CarrierData...In Specialities  column the values are saving like 4' Tarps, 6' Tarps, 8' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card

Comment: in ui search there is a dropdown multi selected ..which comes like suppose two value selected  Coil Racks, Edge Protectors ...here i want to match the column with these value and fetch the row which is matched

Comment: @YogeshSharma any question??

Comment: you can look the image..

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: `4' Tarps` Those embedded single quotes are going to bite you hard, have a look at how many single quotes you use even if the variable does not contain a single quote. Goodness, make your life easier, redesign it. *(& gosh aren't I happy not to be using antique units of measure)*

Comment: @Used_By_Already there already inserted a lakhs of value so i used to replace

Comment: fyi: `lakh` isn't widely used. I trust you have a backup in case you need it, don't react to suggestions without careful consideration.

Comment: @asasasaa Did you got solution? Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shall try to change the database schema.

**Other Option -** 
You can convert CSV into Table, the sample Query is as below

```
DECLARE @strString VARCHAR(max)

SET @strString = '4'' Tarps, 6'' Tarps, 8'' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card'

DECLARE @x XML

SELECT
    @x = CAST('<Specialities><node>' +
     REPLACE(@strString, ',', '</node></Specialities><Specialities><node>') 
     + '</node></Specialities>' AS XML)

SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
        t.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Specialities
    FROM @x.nodes('//Specialities ') AS t (c)) AS final

--to declare WHERE Condition as needed, Uncomment the below  line

--WHERE final.Specialities LIKE '%Tarps%'
```

The final result will be shown as below

```
+--------------+
| Specialities |
+--------------+
| 4' Tarps     |
|  6' Tarps    |
|  8' Tarps    |
+--------------+
```

**EDIT**

To search entire table rows and columns - below is the update in SQL Syntax using **COALESCE**

```
DECLARE @strString VARCHAR(max)

--SET @strString = '4'' Tarps, 6'' Tarps, 8'' Tarps, Coil Racks, Edge Protectors, TWIC Card'
--GETTING @strString directly from the table
-- Assuming the column name is Specialities

SELECT
    @strString = COALESCE(@strString + ',', '') + Specialities
FROM <WriteYourTableNameHere>

DECLARE @x XML

SELECT
    @x = CAST('<Specialities><node>' +
     REPLACE(@strString, ',', '</node></Specialities><Specialities><node>') 
     + '</node></Specialities>' AS XML)

SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
        t.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Specialities
    FROM @x.nodes('//Specialities ') AS t (c)) AS final

--to declare WHERE Condition as needed, Uncomment the below  line

--WHERE final.Specialities LIKE '%%'
```

This will give result as below

```
+------------------+
|   Specialities   |
+------------------+
| 4' Tarps         |
|  6' Tarps        |
|  8' Tarps        |
|  Coil Racks      |
|  Edge Protectors |
|  TWIC Card       |
| Partials         |
| None             |
| Partials         |
|  TWIC Card       |
| 4' Tarps         |
|  6' Tarps        |
|  Edge Protectors |
+------------------+
```

**Conclusion** Though this solution works fine it have its own risks in terms of performance and invalid comma (,) in the table rows. Those you need to handle based on how data is stored